# Array index manipulation php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have a question here. Let's say I have an array of the form:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [A] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 1
                             [firstname] => John
                             [lastname] => Smith
                             [email] => jsmith@gmail.com
                         )

                     [B] => Array
                         (
                         )

                 )

         )

     [1] => Array
         (
             [0] => Array
                 (
                     [A] => Array
                         (
                             [id] => 2
                             [firstname] => Tommy
                             [lastname] => Tom
                             [email] => ttom@gmail.com
                         )

                     [B] => Array
                         (
                         )

                 )

         )

)
```

How can I replace the index of the outer array by the index of the inner array in order to have an array like this:

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [A] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [firstname] => John
                        [lastname] => Smith
                        [email] => jsmith@gmail.com
                    )

                [B] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )



        [1] => Array
            (
                [A] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [firstname] => Tommy
                        [lastname] => Tom
                        [email] => ttom@gmail.com
                    )

                [B] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )



)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted this, seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: The difference I can see in the two is that third level array becomes the second level array. Have you tried to simply go: `unusualArray[0] = unusualArray[0][0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through the arrays and create a new array based on the inner values.

```
$in_array = <your array>;
$out_array = Array();

foreach($in_array as $k => $v) {
    $out_array[$k] = array_shift($v);
}
```

Here, `$out_array[$k]` keeps the original top-level array keys, and `array_shift($v)` says to dig down one level for the values (taking the value at the first element in the mid-level array using `array_shift`, and applying it as the value for the new array).

Answer (score 3):

Another option, for your particular case, could be as simple as:

```
$out = array_map('reset', $in);
```

Comment: +1, good thinking! Ruby being my main language, I really should have thought of this one =).

Answer (score -1):

```
//$array is your array
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
   $new_array[] = $array[$key];
}
```